# Traveling from Shanghai's Pudong airport (PVG) to Hangzhou

Tags: public-transport, china, shanghai

In April I will land at Shanghai's PVG airport in the late afternoon and attempt to then get to Hangzhou that evening. I don't speak Mandarin and I will have been flying for 20 hours, so I expect to be a bit wiped out!  Any guidance on how best to get a train or bus to Hangzhou? (I wouldn't mind the high speed train but I think PVG is a long way from the closest terminal)

Do I need to purchase a bus or train ticket in advance?  Will there be ticket stations where people speak (a little) English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @dda's answer,

- There is [a direct bus from PVG to Hongqiao](https://www.travelchinaguide.com/cityguides/shanghai/transportation/pudong-airport-bus.htm). (but the information might not always be accurate, as it frequently changes.)
- Except the very busy season, the ticket is available at the counter. There are enough tickets even 30 minutes before the departure.
- People at ticket counters speak a little English, but the communication might not pun out smoothly.
- There are two arrival stations at Hangzhou - Hangzhou station and Hangzhou East station. Hangzhou station is closer to the city centre and more convenient for most people.
- You can use [Ctrip](https://english.ctrip.com/) to check the timetable in English.

Answer (score 4):

There are **lots** of trains going to Hangzhou, from Shanghai South (regular trains) and Hongqiao (high-speed trains). [This website](http://m.tieyou.com/daigou?from=%E4%B8%8A%E6%B5%B7&to=%E6%9D%AD%E5%B7%9E&date=utf-8) gives you the schedule and prices. It's in Chinese: the 2-hour rides are Shanghai South-Hangzhou, the 45-60-minute rides from Hongqiao.

From Pudong to Hongqiao, you'll need 1.5 hours, Maglev and metro line 2. By taxi it could take forever and a day. Traffic there is mental, and late afternoons, oh well.

I suggest you print out "杭州站" (Hangzhou station) and present that (and your passport, plus a 100-yuan bill) to the ticket booth at Hongqiao station. You'll get a ticket, some change and your passport back.